# How to extend function constructor with class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

Is there any easy way to inherit `function constructor` from `class`?

For example I have this code:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.parentField = 1;
  }
}

function Child() {
  // Parent.call(this); // TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'
  
  this.childField = 2;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Child, Parent);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);

const child = new Child();

console.log(child);
```

As you can see the problem is when I try to call `constructor` of `class`

The easiest way which I came up is to move code from `constructor` into `class.prototype.initialize`:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.initialize();
  }
  
  initialize() {
    this.parentField = 1;
  }
}

function Child() {
  Parent.prototype.initialize.call(this);
  
  this.childField = 2;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Child, Parent);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);

const child = new Child();

console.log(child);
```

What if the `class` is written in some library or for some reason I don’t have access to this `class`?

The easiest way which I came up is to "recreate" the `constructor` of `class`:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.parentField = 1;
  }
}

function ParentConstructor(...args) {
  const parent = new Parent(...args);

  for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(parent)) {
    this[key] = parent[key];
  }
  
  // or
  // Object.setPrototypeOf(this, parent);
  // but in this case I will not see the public keys of parent
}

function Child() {
  ParentConstructor.call(this);

  this.childField = 2;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Child, Parent);
Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);

const child = new Child();

console.log(child);
```

I want to know are there better ways to inherit `function constructor` from `class` for both situations:

1. I have access to `class`
2. I haven't access to `class`

Comment: So what about `super()`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `class Child extends Parent`?

Comment: @Pointy Doesn't super works only in methods or classes? Can you please give an example in answer?

Comment: @Barmar Of course not, just wondering. Because if `Parent` is function and `Child` is class then I just need to write `class Child extends Parent`

Comment: `super` works in methods of classes, but that's the code you have in your question (except your Child does not extend Parent, but I assumed you left that out by accident). If normal `class` code is not what you're talking about, you'll need to edit and supply more information because it's really not clear.

Comment: @Teemu right, you can't *call* `super()` but in methods you can use `super` to get to parent properties right? (I've never been in a situation where that made sense, but I think it works.)

Comment: @Teemu `Parent.constructor` is `Function`, that doesn't do the trick. And you cannot do `Parent.call(this)`, it'll throw an exception.

Comment: @Poiny It looks like you can't, "_SyntaxError: super() is only valid in derived class constructors_",

Comment: @Bergi Indeed, I haven't mixed these either, I should've tested to the end, I just checked no error occurred.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! It is "composition" way which I tried to workaround. But now it is clear that I can't do this

Comment: @Teemu no I mean `let foo = super.something;` and no I can't think of why, but I think it's supposed to work. Probably for when the child class overrides a parent method and you want the parent version, but to me that's a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheriting a class constructor in a function can be achieved **by calling the class constructor within the function** and **manually setting the prototype chain**.

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.parentField = 1;
  }
}

function Child() {
  let instance = Reflect.construct(Parent, arguments, new.target || Child);
  instance.childField = 2;
  return instance;
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype);

const child = new Child();

console.log(child);
```